# Let's think of a creative name for our chatroom

Tags: discussion, chat

The chatroom name is so bland. "Vim." Look at all the creative names others have thought up:

- "Root Access" for Super User
- "The DMZ" for Security
- "The Renderfarm" for Blender
- "The Litter Box" for Pets
- "The Hangar" for Aviation
- "You Are Here" for Travel
- "The Water Cooler" for The Workplace
- "The Whiteboard" for Programmers
- "The Nineteenth Byte" for Code Golf
- etc...

Can we think of a better name for our chatroom?

Only one idea per answer, please. Vote up the ideas that you like!

<sup>Stolen from [Coffee meta](https://coffee.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4/63), which was in turn stolen from [Lifehacks meta](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25/88), which was stolen from [PPCG meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1005/3808). But that's okay, because I wrote all of those posts too. :P</sup>

Comment: You forgot 'Software Recommendations' for Software Recommendations. That's the most creative one.

Comment: @Undo But that's just because we couldn't agree on a better one..

Comment: Do you know you can actually chat with vi? You can use [`ii`](http://tools.suckless.org/ii/), and write to the sockets with vi/vim. Did that for a while, had all sorts of keybinds for sending commands and such...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## :chat

It's obvious what it means, and it's vi-y.

Comment: I want to chat no matter what so I want to `:chat!`

Comment: @yo' - The ! adds some great energy to it, too.

Comment: I shared my thoughts as another answer... What about `set :chat`?

Answer (score 20):

### The Escape

Most of your examples started with "The" and the escape key is commonly used in vim. Also, a chat is a place to escape from other things for a while.

Comment: Updated with capital E

Comment: We should abbreviate it to The Esc.

Comment: I don't like TLAs that much and even the long form is cryptic enough, imo. But it's on the community at large to decide :-)

Comment: I wonder if we can just name it `^[`

Answer (score 8):

### How do I get out?

I just had to.

Comment: Nice joke, bad name for a room, at least in my opinion.

Comment: I think it's great!

Comment: maybe "go out" (i.e., have a party) rather then "get out" (i.e., I don't wanna be here)? What about **Let me go out!**? Ah, I can try that one myself and we'll see ;)

Answer (score 4):

## Home Row

Another idea.

Answer (score 3):

## :set buftype=chat

Possibly a bit *too* esoteric?

Answer (score 1):

## BufWrite

Or any of the other [autocommand-events](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#autocmd-events).

Comment: [`UserGettingBored`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#UserGettingBored)?

Answer (score 1):

## <CR>

A pretty familiar symbol to Vimmers.  In this case it stands for chat room, not carriage return.

Answer (score -1):

In response to @Carpetsmoker and @Rich...

## set :chat

---

When checking out [all Vim options](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickref.html#option-list)

## set :title titlestring=chat

Answer (score -4):

## Normal Mode

Not terribly clever, but simple and clear.

Comment: Wouldn't the main site be Normal Mode? I'd be tempted by 'Insert Visual Mode', though, just because its a funny name :-/

Comment: Maybe 'Chat mode', or 'Talk mode'...

Comment: Why not 'Insert mode'? It's for typing in, not editing.